# how to store user input data in your react native app

Tags: react-native, storage

i know its possible to store data using local storage for a web app but how would i do this for a react native app. the app I've made allows the user to enter a phone number into the input field and it will call that number. I also have a login page. I would like the last number they entered into the input field still be there when they re open the app. heres the code below

```
<View>
<Text style={styles.phoneNumberTitle}>PHONE NUMBER</Text></View>
<TextInput style={styles.inputs}
ref={(el)=>{this.recipient=el;}}
onChangeText={(recipient)=>this.setState({recipient})}
value={this.state.recipient}/>

<Button title="CALL"
style={styles.callButtCont}
onPress={this.setTimer.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**
`AsyncStorage` is Deprecated. Use [react-native-community/react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) instead.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

`AsyncStorage` is a simple, unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of LocalStorage.

import `AsyncStorage` at the top :-

```
import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'
```

set like this :-

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("recipient", this.state.recipient);
```

and access like this :-

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("recipient").then((value) => {
   alert("Get recipient >> ", value);
}).done();
```

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html